# How can I give today's date as default value for a parameter in powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'd like to create a script that helps to copy files modified in a time range. I would like to leave the `$EndDate` parameter as optional and in such-case, I'd like the script to use today's date as Default.

Below is the Script:

```
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$Path,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$targetDir,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$BeginDate,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
  [string]$EndDate,

  [switch]$force
)

 Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $BeginDate -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $EndDate }| cp -Destination $targetDir -Force
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][string]$enddate = Get-Date,
```

give it a default value like so, you may also want to format it:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][string]$enddate = (Get-Date -f dd\MM\yy)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[string]$EndDate = Get-Date
```

I would not advise formatting it as this turns it from a `DateTime` type to a `String` data type, leading to issues in your `Where-Object`

**Edit:** Just realised you are explicitly casting as `[string]`. AFAIK this'll break your `Where-Object` as you are comparing `DateTime` to string(unless PowerShell automagically casts the `$EndDate`as `DateTime`...).

This makes it more robust. If [4c74356b41's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060500/5039142) get's you what you want, go with that!

---

```
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$Path,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$targetDir,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$BeginDate,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
  [string]$EndDate = (Get-Date),

  [switch]$force
)

try{
    [datetime]$BeginDate = $BeginDate
}catch{
    Write-Output "$BeginDate is not a valid datetime"
}

try{
    [datetime]$EndDate = $EndDate 
}catch{
    Write-Output "$EndDate is not a valid datetime"
}

 Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $BeginDate -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $EndDate }| cp -Destination $targetDir -Force
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realised and am updating answer. Leads to errors in OP's code so not really "whatever"

Comment: I'm a bit too lazy to test this, but i would assume that powershell can cast it back and forth

Comment: @4c74356b41 I'd like to think that it would take the type of the first part in the `Where-Object` (`$_.LastWriteTime`) and implicitly convert the second part to this type. But not sure so prefer to be explicit (normally work with "untyped" data so used to this approach)

Comment: Thanks a lot @gms0ulman. Is their easier way to convert the parameter into Date format at the parameter level itself?

Comment: @Kiran You could cast `$EndDate` and `$BeginDate` as `[datetime]` instead of `[string]` at the parameter. Bear in mind the script will error and not launch if an invalid datetime is entered.